# Unable to read XML node value using php - throwing error as 'allocated memory exhausted'

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file with size around 305MB. I am using the below code to parse that XML.

```
$objDOM = new DOMDocument();
$loadXmlResult = @$objDOM->loadXML($responseXml);
$systemsTag = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("system");
foreach($systemsTag as $systemItemValue) {
   $asupsTag = $systemItemValue->getElementsByTagName("asup");
   foreach ($asupsTag as $asupItem) {
      $contentList = $asupItem->getElementsByTagName("list");
      foreach ($contentList as $contentListItem) {
          $sectionDataTag = $contentListItem->getElementsByTagName("data");
          $data = trim($sectionDataTag->item(0)->nodeValue); //Here I am getting error as 'allocated memory exhausted'
      }
   }
}
```

As I mentioned above, from this line "$data = trim($sectionDataTag->item(0)->nodeValue);" I am getting the above error.

We are using PHP libxml version 2.6.26. If I upgrade this PHP libxml to 2.7 or higher, will I get any benefits for parsing the big XML files?

The data has a lot of child nodes in that (because of confidentiality I cannot share the data).

Is there anyway to fix this issue other than increasing memory limit (within PHP) OR any other solution to parse big size XML files like python or perl?.

Please suggest...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Combine XMLReader with DOM. Basically iterate the outer/list nodes (`system`) with XMLReader and expand them into DOM. That way only one `system` node and its descendants will be loaded into memory at a time.

Here is an example to give you a general idea:

```
$reader = new XMLReader;
$reader->open($file);
$document = new DOMDocument;
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// look for the first system element
while ($reader->read() && $reader->localName !== 'system') {
  continue;
}

// while you have an system element
while ($reader->localName === 'system') {
  $node = $reader->expand($document);
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('.//asup//list//data', $node) as $dataNode) {
    var_dump(
      trim($dataNode->textContent)
    );
  }
  // move to the next system sibling
  $reader->next('system');
}
```

If the `system` + descendants is still to large you might need to move another node level from DOM to XMLReader.

DOM not only has methods like `DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()` but allows you to use Xpath expressions. Xpath expression are powerful and allow you fetch specific nodes/values directly.